# Cast IEnumerable to IEnumerable<T> when T is unknown at compile time

Tags: c#, generics

I have a sorting extension method with the following signature:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> CustomSort<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, string sortProperties)
```

We wrote it a while back and it has been doing its thing. Now I am creating a custom control and the DataSource property is an IEnumerable (non-generic).
Is there any way to get the type of the objects in a non-generic IEnumerable?

I am sure the problem of "sort a custom control data source" has been solved a million times, but I just can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an extension method that will return the correct type at runtime:

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static Type GetElementType(this IEnumerable source)
    {
        var enumerableType = source.GetType();
        if (enumerableType.IsArray)
        {
            return enumerableType.GetElementType();
        }
        if (enumerableType.IsGenericType)
        {
            return enumerableType.GetGenericArguments().First();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Update: I've added the mechanism that I would use to perform the generic-specific `IEnumerable<T>` sorting on the non-generic `IEnumerable`

```
public static class SortingExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> CustomSort<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, string sortProperties)
    {
        // sort here
    }

    public static IEnumerable CustomSort(this IEnumerable source, string sortProperties)
    {
        var elementType = source.GetElementType();
        var genericElementType = typeof (IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(elementType);

        var sortMethod = typeof (SortingExtensions).GetMethod(
            "CustomSort", 
            BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static,
            null, 
            new [] {genericElementType, typeof (string)},
            null);

        return (IEnumerable) sortMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] {source, sortProperties});
    }

}
```

Comment: Interesting approach. I'll give it a try as well. About the sort method, this is more or less what we are doing, but we also take in to account sorting with multiple properties, each with its own direction.

Comment: I tried your solution, but enumerableType.GetGenericArguments().First() causes a StackOverflowException. (Havn't had one of these in ages! :))

Comment: I found the issue. Once the method goes through public static IEnumerable CustomSort(this IEnumerable source, string sortProperties) it is called again, and this creates an infinate loop, or so it seems.

Comment: In `Invoke` you pass `source` as the first parameter, and it calls the non-generic method again. This causes an infinate loop.

Comment: I renamed your `CustomSort` to `CustomSort2` and then `sortMethod` is null.

Comment: Finally figured it out! Since `CustomSort<T>` is a generic method, you need to add `MakeGenericMethod(genericElementType)`. Thank you!

Comment: There is a possible bug, when a `IEnumerable<T>` is extended like this: `class AnotherClass<T> : IEnumerable<int>`. For this issue the basetype `IEnumerable<>` must be found first.

Answer (score 5):

There is a fundamental issue here that a type can implement IEnumerable-of-T for multiple T at the same time. But if we exclude that case, a cheeky approach is:

```
void Evil<T>(IEnumerable<T> data) {...}

IEnumerable source = ...
dynamic cheeky = source;
Evil(cheeky);
```

This basically offloads this problem to the DLR, letting your Evil-of-T method take it easy.

Comment: This assumes that `source` actually implements `IEnumerable<T>` for some `T`; many data sources in .NET date from before generics and thus actually only implement `IEnumerable`, in which case your code crashes with a `RuntimeBinderException`.

Comment: @Timwi the question asks about "casting" it. It is only possible to cast it if it does indeed implement the generic version for some T. I don't disagree with you - I'm just saying that this dependency is implicit in the question.

Comment: @Timwi - Marc is correct in his assumption that the origin of the non-generic IEnumerable (the DataSource) is a List<T> of some T, which is unknown to me at compile time. Thus it should implement IEnumerable<T>.

Comment: How would I implement this in my situation? The method is an extension method on IEnumerable<T>... And what do I need to pass as the generic parameter? I understand the concept of your solution, but I'm lacking in the mechanics of making it happen :)

Comment: @elad you can't use extension syntax with dynamic - just have your extension method call a second method via explicit SomeType.Evil(cheeky) syntax

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would just use

```cs
DataSource.Cast<object>()
```

and then you have an `IEnumerable<object>` that you can use in your `CustomSort<T>` function. I am assuming here that this function can handle arbitrary objects already; judging by the second parameter name I’m guessing that you’re using Reflection in it anyway, so it should be fine. Just make sure it uses each object’s `GetType()` when reflecting on it, not `typeof(T)`, because `typeof(T)` will obviously be `object` and it won’t get the list of fields of the actual object.

Of course, if you actually know the type of all the objects in the data source at compile-time, you might want to use that type instead, e.g.:

```
DataSource.Cast<Customer>()
```

Comment: You're right about the MoveNext(). I already deleted that line by the time I created this post, so I was writing from memory. About the Cast<>, I'll try it. Thank you!

Comment: @EladLachmi: OK, then I’ll take the liberty to remove that part from your question also.

Comment: The CustomSort<T> function uses typeof(T) in reflection to construct the sort as a lambda expression. I would rather leverage what we have, than create something new (which will need to go through QA, etc, etc, etc... You know how it is :))